# Installing FastQueryBuilder Component Fails to install into Delphi XE2 IDE

Tags: delphi-xe2

I am trying to install FastQueryBuilder component set into Delphi XE2.

I can build everything that is required, but when I go to install `dslfqb100.bpl`, I get the message shown below.

I have a VM where I have the exact same files and paths set up, and the component installs perfectly.

Can anyone help?

> The procedure entry point @Fqbutilities@initialization$qqrv could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Bpl\dclfqb100.bpl.

Answer (score 0):

XE2 is BDS version 9.0
Package name show version 10 which is supposed to be XE3.
Are you trying to install package for XE3 to XE2 ?
Try and build correct package